# Install cURL library to satisfy dependency for R on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: package-management, curl, r

I am trying to install curl library. It is a dependency for the `RCurl` package in R. So I must install it for R to work properly. I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-opensll-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcurl4-opensll-dev
```

I found a similar problem in the three links below. But they did not help solve my dilemma.

- [Need libcurl (on Ubuntu Forums)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876552)
- [Broken curl packages (on Ubuntu Forums)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1890584)
- [The program 'curl' is currently not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259681/the-program-curl-is-currently-not-installed)

I need the following for `Rcurl` to work: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-opensll-dev`.

Comment: You have typo. It should "libcurl4-openssl-dev" instead of "libcurl4-opensll-dev"

Comment: Sorry...changing typo fixed it. My bad.

Answer (score 8):

For PHP:

**install curl**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

**restart apache**

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Answer (score 6):

You can install [Curl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/curl) simply by :

```
sudo apt-get install curl libc6 libcurl3 zlib1g
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following -

```
mkdir xxx
cd xxx
```

for 32 bit use-

```
wget http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libcurl4-openssl-dev/download
```

For 64 bit use-

```
wget http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libcurl4-openssl-dev/download
```

For knowing the name of package_name.deb  downloaded file use -

```
ls
```

For Installation use -

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

Just write the name of the package instead of package_name.deb as you got it from previous command ls.

Hope it helped you.