# sudo apt-get curl and sudo apt-get wget gives "Invalid operation"

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, wget

I am very fresh in Linux. I tried to use the sudo apt-get command to install both wget and curl **utilities**. To do that I ran at the following CLI commands:

```
sudo apt-get curl
sudo apt-get wget
```

Both inputs give the error `Invalid operation`; No further information is given.

I tried to do `man invalid` || `man Invalid`, but there seem to be no entries for these terms.

Google search yielded zero results for "sudo apt-get wget" + "invalid operation".

For curl problem I did found [a solution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259681/the-program-curl-is-currently-not-installed) but I would humbly prefer having an expert's take on this before trying it (as I really need wget as well and want to understand the root of the problem).

Comment: And what are these command supposed to do? `wget` is installed by default, so if you need it, use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `apt-get` does not have any option like `curl` or `wget`.

Perhaps you wanted to install/upgrade the packages, if so then:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
sudo apt-get install curl
```

The package name goes as argument to `apt-get`'s option e.g. `install`, `remove` etc.